# Is there a way to check if the user who installed my app has really installed my app?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, app-store, google-play

I need to check, using APPLE ID/GOOGLE Android ID, if the user really has paid to buy my app.

I have to avoid an user use a cracked app (jailbreak)

Is there a "public key" unique for each app? I can use that (if exist) to check the unifier of my app

Comment: You cannot get the current user's apple id in the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No. You do not have access to this information via the API, but as others have said, you can roll your own solution via in-app purchases and your own server. If your concern is that unlicensed users will consume server bandwidth or other expensive resources, I'd suggest doing this.

If your end goal is just to prevent piracy, though, I'd suggest googling some of the off-the-shelf anti-piracy solutions available today. Even then, however, I would not expect miracles. I have implemented as many anti-piracy techniques as I can develop within a few of my own clients' apps, but to date, none of them remain "uncracked."

Comment: Ok, to check via API, do I need to ask to my user its " apple I'd"? What's official documentation page?

Comment: You could always ask, although I'm not sure what you'd compare this against, as Apple does not provide a list of purchasers' Apple IDs (and I know I would not use my real ID if asked  by a third party). There is no API for this, and thus, no official documentation. Apple's stance (whether naive or unconcerned) seems to be that if an app has been installed, it is assumed to be a legitimate copy (which is true on a non-jailbroken device, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something creative involving in-app-purchase and pinging your own server when the purchase is completed. This assumes you want to put content behind the IAP paywall and that you want to run your own server which perhaps isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, use the [license verification library](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could make it available for free on the AppStore, and then use a `licensing` or `in-app purchases` to deliver more content (full-content) to the users !